# Is there any advantage in signup before login when using social plugins

Tags: html, oauth

I am building a site and was thinking about if there should be a signup option at all.

I found this but there was neither an accepted answer nor enough responses.
[Difference between sign up with Facebook/Google/etc and log in with Facebook/Google/etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21671368/difference-between-sign-up-with-facebook-google-etc-and-log-in-with-facebook-goo#)

What is the advantage of having to signup using facebook/ google in the first place. As I see it, a direct login simply would imply checking if the email exists in your database and if not add that info.
Since, this would be just a one time operation, I don't buy that a one time insert would take too much time or ruin user experience. Am I wrong on this part?

Then I see all major sites including SO using the signup with google etc. so there must be something to the point of signup before login.

Can somebody please explain why signup users at all?
I can't think of more tags to go along with this question so please add as appropriate.

Comment: Have you checked out http://ux.stackexchange.com

Comment: Not yet. Will do now. Should I move this over there?

Comment: what if the user visiting your site don't have a  facebook/ google account to begin with?

Comment: @bansi, I get and understand the point and utility of your domain signup. The question is about social signups

Comment: @NaveenSharma I would. This isn't really a programming related question, and a discussion about this will probably be a lot more fun there.